# I send a parameter to method but it always returns null

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C I send a parameter to method but it always returns null.

My code:

```
-(IBAction) clickNumero: (id) sender
{   
    NSString *num = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];
    float numFloat = [num floatValue];
    [self verificarOperador:(float)numFloat];
}

-(float) verificarOperador:(float)valor
{   
    return valor;
}
```

Comment: Seems like SPAM. Is this a real question? If so, code looks good, you're just not assigning the return value to anything.

Comment: I guess this is for iOS: rename the method, you cannot click on a touch screen. (Yeah even Apple forgot this in the UIActionSheetDelegate protocol, oh well.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure -currentTitle is returning a numeric string only?  You should add `NSLog(@"Button Title: %@", num);`  to make sure.